# C# how to specify only a part of types in the generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to write an generic method with some types so that only one of them is specified when used?

something like this:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public static TOut Bar<T1, T2, T3, TOut>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3)
    {
        TOut destination;

        // other logic here

        return destination;
    }
}
```

To use it like this:

```cs
foo.Bar<TOut>()
```

Because the compiler understands T1 - T3 by arguments and it can be enough to specify only the TOut :)

Comment: You can't.  The options are to specify none of them or all of them.  Or make another generic with one parameter.

Comment: it's impossible by your current example. can you add more context? like `where` clause.

Comment: Your example in "To use it like this" doesn't show the method accepting any parameters at all, but the function signature has it accepting three parameters.

Answer (score 3):

It is not allowed in c#. The rule is so, you need to specify both generic arguments or none of the them if inference is possible. By the way, when compiler  detects type based on the specified value it is called ***Type Inference***.

For achieving the desired result, I have two offers for you.

1) You can change the design of your class in that way:

```
public class Foo<T1, T2, T3>
{
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
    T3 t3;

    public Foo(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3)
    {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
        this.t3 = t3;
    }

    public TOut Bar<TOut>()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public static Foo<T1, T2, T3> CreateFoo<T1, T2, T3>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3)
    {
        return new Foo<T1, T2, T3>(t1, t2, t3);
    }
}
```

And then call `Bar` in that way:

```
 var foo = Foo.CreateFoo(4,"", "");
 var result = foo.Bar<string>();
```

By the way, I implemented `CreateFoo` method, because constrcutors are not supporting type inference.

2) Or as a second approach I can offer you to make use of ***`out`***:

```
class Foo
{
    public static void Bar<T1, T2, T3, TOut>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, out TOut tOut)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And then use it so:

```
Foo.Bar(5, 4, 6, out string x);
```

Comment: no way.  what if the `Bar` has overloads, like `Foo(T4 t1)`?

Comment: @Dongdong Of course, there might be such  limitations. I just tried to show him some possible ways. In those case, he can change `Foo(T4 t4)` to `Foo(T4 t4, TOut tOut)`.

Comment: @Dongdong I guess different overloads has same mission. Because, normally implementation of such overload 's are very similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a dummy `TOut` argument to the method, then you can sort of achieve what you want:

```
public static TOut Bar<T1, T2, T3, TOut>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, TOut dummy)
{
    TOut destination;

    // other logic here

    return destination;
}

// use it here:
// Bar<int,string,float,string>
var result = Bar(1, "two", 3.0, default(string))

// Bar<string,SomeClass,int,SomeStruct>
var result = Bar("x", new SomeClass(), 32, default(SomeStruct))
```